# Asp.net Авторизация через web api с использованием membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Как авторизоваться и зарегистрироваться через web api с использованием membership. При использовании

```
Membership.ValidateUser(login, password)
```

или

```
WebSecurity.Login(login, password)
```

для регистрации

```
WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(login, password)
```

иногда выдает ошибку следуещего типа

```
{"$id":"1","Message":"An error has occurred."}.
```

Но иногда все работает замечательно. Или как можно сравнить пароли с базы данных и введенный пользователем пароль?

Comment: пароли лучше хранить в виде sha1 хеш-сумм. далее сравнивать хеш-сумму введённого пароля с той что в базе. возможно не помешает добавить немного соли :)